# Can I create a table without a primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a table without a primar key:

users_models

user_id
model_id

I have a users table, but the model_id value is actually going to come from a enumeration that I have in my code.

So I don't need a primary key on this table, can I in my migration tell it so it doesn't create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your migration change :

```
 create_table :users, {:id => false, :force => true}
```

Comment: it forces the migration even if the table exists.